# Multiple database in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, jpa

I am using Spring boot, JPA and mysql for Rest API

I have Employee model, Employee Controller, Employee Service, Employee Repository and two database db1 and db2.

In employee Controller I will get company_Id as parameter.

if company_Id is 1, then I have to use db1 or db2.

If it is possible then please share any sample codes or links.

Comment: I suppose you're not elaborate your requirements properly. Please give some proper description so community users suggest something useful to you or provide proper way to clear your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In your persistence.xml, you can define 2 persistence units

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="EmployeeController">
    -- Data source, properties etc.
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyEmployeeDB</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="EmployeeControllerCompany1">
    -- Data source, properties etc.
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyEmployeeCompany1DB</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
<persistence>
```

So you will call different services depending on whether your `company_Id` is 1 or not. In you service that deals with `company_Id == 1`, you retrieve an entity manager referring to the rlevant persistence-unit

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EmployeeControllerCompany1");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager( );
```

The JPA Spec itself descibes this quite well
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html